# Assert.AreEqual vs Assert.IsTrue/Assert.IsFalse

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

When testing a method that is of return type bool.

Should you have:

```
expected = true;
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

or

```
Assert.IsTrue(actual);
```

I know they both produce the same outcome, but which is better practise to use?

EDIT: For example, if I do AreEqual, is it not essentially the same as doing IsTrue on a method that returns a string a la below:

```
string expected = “true”;
string actual = test.testMethod(data)
bool test;

if expected.equals(actual)
    test = true;
else 
    test = false;
Assert.IsTrue(test);
```

Comment: Under what circumstances do you have a *variable* `expected` that you *know is always true*? That is, if you know that it is always true then why have a variable in the first place? Just use the literal `true`.

Comment: @EricLippert: He's trying to fit the pattern that VS autogenerates, which looks exactly like that (Right-click a bool-returning method, then click Create Unit Tests).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should only use `Assert.IsTrue` if you're testing something which directly returns a boolean that should always be true.

You should not massage data to get a boolean for `IsTrue`; instead, you should call a more relevant method in `Assert` or `CollectionAssert`.

In your edited example, you should by all means call `Assert.AreEqual` instead; it will give you a much nicer message.

Answer (score 17):

Using `Assert.IsTrue` is clearer and less verbose.

Comment: And the message is better when the test failed.

Comment: @Toto: How is `Assert.IsTrue failed` better?

Comment: i just test. I remember that the message was different but no. Sorry.